# Simple Python Calculator

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I am new to python and I am practicing by making a simple calculator.
The program lets me input numerical values for meal, tax, and tip but when doing the calculation I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chacha04231991/Desktop/pytuts/mealcost.py", line 5, in <module>
    meal = meal + meal * tax
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

The is the code:

```
meal = raw_input('Enter meal cost: ')
tax = raw_input('Enter tax price in decimal #: ')
tip = raw_input('Enter tip amount in decimal #: ')

meal = meal + meal * tax
meal = meal + meal * tip

total = meal
print 'your meal total is ', total
```

Comment: result of the `raw_input` is `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your inputs from strings to numbers, e.g. integers:

```
meal = int(raw_input('Enter meal cost: '))
tax = int(raw_input('Enter tax price in decimal #: '))
tip = int(raw_input('Enter tip amount in decimal #: '))
```

You could also use the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) type if you need to enter fractional monetary amounts.

```
from decimal import Decimal 
meal = Decimal(raw_input('Enter meal cost: '))
tax = Decimal(raw_input('Enter tax price in decimal #: '))
tip = Decimal(raw_input('Enter tip amount in decimal #: '))
```

I would advise you not to use floats for this because it will give rounding errors.

Comment: It works fine using float but when I try decimal is gives this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chacha04231991/Desktop/pytuts/mealcost.py", line 4, in <module>
    tax = decimal(raw_input('Enter tax price in decimal #: '))
NameError: name 'decimal' is not defined

Comment: @codeYah: `decimal` with a small `d` is the name of the module. The type `Decimal` has a capital `D`.

Answer (score 1):

when you use raw_input, the input you get is of type `str`

```
>>> meal = raw_input('Enter meal cost: ')
Enter meal cost: 5
>>> type(meal)
<type 'str'>
```

you should convert it to `int`/`float` before performing action

```
>>> meal = int(raw_input('Enter meal cost: '))
Enter meal cost: 5
>>> type(meal)
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input is a string by default in python. You will have to convert it to an integer before multiplying.

```
int(meal)
int(tax)
int(tip)
```

should do the trick.

[Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/python-parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and also I wrote this code depending on the user operand input as string..

```
def calculator(a, b, operand):
    result = 0
    if operand is '+':
      result = a + b
    elif operand is '-':
      result = a - b
    elif operand is '*':
      result = a * b
    elif operand is '/':
      result = a / b
    return result

calculator(2, 3, '+')
output -> 5
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, python assumes all input as string value. So we need to convert string values to numbers through either float or int.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.